# How can I make sure the long text is horizontally and vertically centered within the circle shapes

Tags: html, css

How can I centre the text within the circle shapes both horizontally and vertically and put equal spacing between each text block?

Comment: maybe you can change  the circle-multi from h3 to div and the text will be the h3 so you can take control of the text and change it as you like

Comment: @sweaver2112: Thank you for your comment, but may I ask if I don't know? I tried to solve that already one week before I asked.

Answer (score 0):

In various way you can achieve it. You can wrap the text in circle within a div so you can give it a absolute property. Here is what I mean:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="circle-multi">
      <h3>Lege dein Gebiet in 30 Minuten an</h3>
    </div>

<div class="circle-txt">

Das Einrichten der Haltestellen und der Gebietsgrenzen ist sehr einfach und kann durch den Verkehrsbetrieb in maximal 30 Minuten durchgeführt werden.

</div></li>
    <li>
    <div class="circle-multi">
<h3>Weniger
Leerfahrten</h3>
    </div>
<div class="circle-txt">Nachmittags und auch am Wochenende fahren tausende Busfahrer in leeren Bussen durch die Gemeinden. B.USnow macht die Leerfahrten buchbar und schöpft die Kapazitäten in ihrer Gemeinde besser aus.</div></li>
    <li>
    <div class="circle-multi">
<h3>Nutzung der vorhandenen Infrastruktur</h3>
    </div>
<div class="circle-txt">B.USnow führt zu einer optimierten Ausschöpfung der bestehenden Kapazitäten. Wir bieten die Mobilitätsplattform und arbeiten eng mit den Verkehrsbetrieben vor Ort zusammen.</div></li>
    <li>
    <div class="circle-multi">
<h3>Flexibilität für die Bürger</h3>
    </div>
<div class="circle-txt">Linienfahrten werden durch B.USnow buchbar gemacht und Bürger können "on Demand" direkt von A nach B gebracht werden.</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-table;
}

.circle-txt {
  text-align: left;

}
.circle-multi {
  border: 5px solid orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
    font-style:bold;
    color:#419eb1;
  text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-multi h3 {
  position: absolute;
  /* Push it 50% from top & left */
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  /* Push it back of it's own width & height by 50% so it will be absolutely in center */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Here is the live preview](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/oVeXKo)

Comment: Thanks for your help:) I will try it again:)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.father {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-rigth: 50px;
max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.circle-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 border: 3px solid red; 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-wrapper h3 {
  max-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-after {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
  <h3>Round 1</h3>
</div>
<span class="text-after">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
  <h3>Round 2</h3>
</div>
<span class="text-after">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
  <h3>Round 3</h3>
</div>
<span class="text-after">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help:)